# How to split a column value following a pattern

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am trying to split the fifth column of a `.pdb` file by adding a space after the chain identifier:

```
ATOM  12107  N   CYS  D1742     -42.369  73.203 -44.599  1.00224.20      C    N
```

So that the output would look like:

```
ATOM  12107  N   CYS  D 1742     -42.369  73.203 -44.599  1.00224.20      C    N
```

The number after the letter changes across the file. I have tried

```
sed -i 's/D/D /5' test.pdb
```

without success and I think I should introduce generalized characters to replace the number which follows the letter and introduce that in the command, in order to be able to do this iteratively.

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '{$5=substr($5,1,1) FS substr($5,2)} 1' OFS="\t"  Input_file
```

In case you need to save the output into same Input_file itself then you could append `> temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file` in above code too.

Comment: I works but I need to keep formatting i.e. tab after columns 5, 9 and 10 otherwise pymol won't read it

Comment: @AlessandraZarantonello, not clear please be more clear in your question here?

Comment: @Ravinder, I think you need to set `OFS="\t"` and use a space instead of OFS when you adjust $5

Comment: @glennjackman, added `OFS="\t"` successfully now thanks for letting me know on same.

Comment: I like your use of string functions for this task. Can also use regular expression search and replace, but it does not increase the clarity: `awk -v OFS="\t" '{sub(/^./, "& ", $5)} 1'`

Comment: You want `" "` not `OFS` between the substr functions.

Answer (score 1):

with `sed` you need to count the fields yourself, but won't normalize the spaces as a side effect.

```
$ sed -E 's/((\S+\s+){4}.)/\1 /' file

ATOM  12107  N   CYS  D 1742     -42.369  73.203 -44.599  1.00224.20      C    N
```

Comment: As the whole of the LHS is used in the RHS another solution is `sed 's/\S\+\s\+\{4\}./& /' file`

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk. Since you did not specify what your field separator is and it seems to be bunches of spaces (yeah, tab most likely), I'm using `split` to preserve separators to array `seps` and `sub` to add the space to the fifth field:

```
$ awk ' {
    n=split($0,a,FS,seps)  # split record to a, preserve separators to seps, keep n
    sub(/D/,"& ",a[5])     # replace first D with D space (not an add :)
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)      # iterate all a
        b=b a[i] seps[i]   # gather to buffer b
    print b; b=""          # output and clear b
}' file
ATOM  12107  N   CYS  D 1742     -42.369  73.203 -44.599  1.00224.20      C    N
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/(\S)(\S*)/\1 \2/5' file
```

A column must consist of one or more non-space characters, this places a space between the first and zero or more characters of the fifth column.